# Clonezilla Live disk clone not working

Tags: clone, clonezilla

My source disk is a 64GB SSD with Ubuntu on it. The target disk is a 250GB SSD.

I'm using clonezilla-live-20150805-vivid-amd64.iso from a USB stick to run CloneZilla.

I'm using the disk to local-disk option. When the clone operation completes and I try to boot from the new disk I just get a black screen with a flashing cursor. LVM is also being used if that makes a difference.

Comment: Have you changed the BIOS/UEFI boot order to prioritise the new SSD?

Comment: @BigChris Yes, I selected the new drive and also removed the old drive so there were no UUID conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to install the GRUB boot loader. Did that using an Ubuntu Live USB in rescue mode.